# How to implement the second loop

Tags: numerics

Here I have a problem that probably needs two loops, but I am not sure how to implement them together. The code calculates `M` for various values of parameter `G`. Now I want to find `M` which crosses the real axis (Imaginary part is zero) for each `α1 = (1.1, 2.2)`. So the code is working fine and for example for `α1 = 1.1`, I got the curve which crosses the real axis, so I have one real solution (for chosen segment `G`), now I want to find these real points `M` for various `α1` and to plot `M[α1]`.

```
 \[Alpha]1 = 1.1;
 \[Nu] = 0.001;
 Tt = 0;
  poly = -g^2 + 0.25 x^4 - (Tt + \[Alpha]1^2) x^2 + 2 \[Alpha]1 g x + 
 I \[Nu] g - I \[Nu] \[Alpha]1 x + 1;

 LM = {};
 Do[Lroots = x /. NSolve[(poly /. {g -> G}) == 0, x];
 res = 0;
 Do[root = Lroots[[i]];
 If[Im[root] >= 0, L1 = Drop[Lroots, {i}];
 res = res + 1/(Times @@ (root - L1));];, {i, 1, Length[Lroots]}];
 M = 1/((4*I*G^2)*res);
  AppendTo[LM, M];, {G, 0.01, 1.5, 0.001}];


   a1 = Min@Select[Table[Im[LM[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[LM]}], Positive];
   a2 = Max@Select[Table[Im[LM[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[LM]}], Negative];

   b1 = Table[LM[[i]], {i, 1, Length[LM]}] - a1*I;
   b2 = Table[LM[[i]], {i, 1, Length[LM]}] - a2*I;

   c1 = Select[b1, Im[#] == 0 &][[1]];
   c2 = Select[b2, Im[#] == 0 &][[1]];

   d1=Re[(c1 + c2)/2]
```

The curve crosses the real axis, but just for `α1 = 1.1`; now I need to extract for various `α1 = 1.1, ..., 2.2`, all points which cross the real axis.

```
 p1 = ListPlot[Table[{Re[LM[[i]]], Im[LM[[i]]]}, {i, 1, Length[LM]}], 
 PlotRange -> {{-1, 18}, {-10, 10}}]
```

Comment: Yes Öskå, from the code I need just one point when the Imaginary part is zero and then to calculate it for various alpha

Comment: not this point, just one which cross the real axis, if doesn't exist it is infinity

Comment: Yes and maybe I should change the G and change the step to see the crossing real axis

Comment: Öskå please take a look now. I made a mistake because of segment. Now for each alpha the plotted curve cross the real axis, I need to extract these points for each alpha and to plot the M(alpha)

Comment: Öskå it is not important to be exact, this is because of chosen step, it is enough just to choose the point with smallest imaginary part and for this point to extract the real value for each alpha on the segment. For all values alpha which I changed the curve cross the real axis for sure, but I just need to do this automatically, not to calculate for each alpha manually

Comment: Öskå Finally I edited the code and found my point d1. Now I need to calculate d1 for each alpha1 automatically and to plot d1(alpha1)

Comment: d1 is my point which I need, I calculated for one alpha1=1.1, now I need d1 for alpha1 = 1.2, 1.3, ... , 2.2; So for each alpha1 I will have my d1, now I need to plot points d1 for each alpha1

Comment: Öskå It is enough just to calculate d1 for each alpha1, not to run code each time to calculate d1

Comment: Check my answer, if you want to calculate `d1` you need to calculate `LM` for each `alpha1` anyway.

Comment: Öskå this is very close, I need on vertical axis value d1 and on horizontal axis alpha1, on diagram I see negative values. I will check the code carefully

Comment: And `d1` is the real or imaginary part of the nearest point to zero?

Comment: my d1 which I calculated is with better accurate because I choose (c1+c2)/2, not nearest. And I don't need Imaginary part in data, just real for each alpha1

Comment: Your Re[data] gives {{1.1, {10.6762}}, {1.2, {3.22105}}, {1.3, {1.60936}}, {1.4, \
{0.854005}}, {1.5, {0.560325}}, {1.6, {0.423807}}, {1.7, {0.311116}}, \
{1.8, {0.242934}}, {1.9, {0.00550994}}, {2., {0.004995}}, {2.1, \
{0.00568088}}, {2.2, {0.00669323}}}; Now I just need to put on horizontal axis alpha and on vertical axis these calculated points and this is it

Comment: Check the edit, and clean the comments afterwards :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tell me if the following fits you. Note that I haven't tried to optimize your code. The idea is simply to put everything under the same function `getNearZero` which depends on `α1`. Then you are free to do every operations you want and do your *second loop* over `α1`.

```
getNearZero[α1_] := 
  Module[{ν, Tt, Poly, g, G, x, M, LM, poly, res, root, Lroots, L1},
    ν = 0.001; Tt = 0;
    poly = -g^2 + 0.25 x^4 - (Tt + α1^2) x^2 + 2 α1 g x + I ν g - I ν α1 x + 1;
    LM = {};
    Do[Lroots = x /. NSolve[(poly /. {g -> G}) == 0, x];
      res = 0;
      Do[root = Lroots[[i]];
        If[Im[root] >= 0, L1 = Drop[Lroots, {i}];
        res = res + 1/(Times @@ (root - L1));];, {i, 1, Length[Lroots]}];
      M = 1/((4*I*G^2)*res);
      AppendTo[LM, M];, {G, 0.01, 1.5, 0.001}]; 
    (* return the Nearest to zero and LM *)
    {Extract[LM, Position[Im /@ LM, First@Nearest[Im /@ LM, 0]]], LM}]
```

Checking if that's the closest point to zero:

```
With[{LM = Last@getNearZero@1.3, nearZero = First@getNearZero@1.3}, 
  ListPlot[Table[{Re[LM[[i]]], Im[LM[[i]]]}, {i, 1, Length[LM]}], 
  PlotRange -> {{-1, 18}, {-10, 10}}, 
  Epilog -> {PointSize@0.02, Red, Point[{First@Re@nearZero, First@Im@nearZero}]}]]
```

[image]

Then you can run the `getNearZero` from `1.1` to `2.2` every `di = 0.1` and `ListLinePlot` the result (note the `Tooltip` showing the corresponding `α1`).

```
data = {#, First@getNearZero@#} & /@ Range[1.1, 2.2, .1];
ListLinePlot[
  Tooltip[#, "α1=" <> ToString@#2] & @@@ 
  Thread[{Thread[{Flatten@Re[Last /@ data], Flatten@Im[Last /@ data]}], First /@ data}],
  Frame -> True, PlotMarkers -> Automatic]
```

[image]

---

If you want to plot the real part of the points nearest to zero in terms of `α1`:

```
ListLinePlot[Thread[{First /@ data, Flatten[Re /@ Last /@ data]}], 
  PlotMarkers -> Automatic, AxesLabel -> {"α1"}]
```

[image]

And finally, if you want to work with your newly edited `ai`, `bi`, `ci` and `d1` the following is shorter:

```
d1 = First @ Mean[Re /@ Extract[LM, Position[Im /@ LM, #]] & /@ Nearest[Im /@ LM, 0, 2]]
```

where `Nearest[Im /@ LM, 0, 2]` replaces your `ai`, the `bi` are not needed anymore, and `Re /@ Extract[LM, Position[Im /@ LM, #]] &` replaces your `ci`.

Comment: Thank you very much Öskå. This is it. I should learn through your code